Old nginx 1.18 version on mac Ventura 13.0 problem
I need to install the old version of nginx 1.18 on Ventura 13.0.
I installed version 1.17.10 via homebrew https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/12ae3226f27a4d767e008465874c1cfc99e8e64d/Formula/nginx.rb and run it via sudo, but the server does not want to go up. Has anyone encountered this problem?
My homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.nginx</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>Aqua</string>
        <string>Background</string>
        <string>LoginWindow</string>
        <string>StandardIO</string>
        <string>System</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/opt/nginx/bin/nginx</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/opt/homebrew</string>
</dict>
</plist>

enter image description here
